# riddle with for(... i++)

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=88444300; i++){
// for(int i=1; i<=88444300; ){
    i *= 2;
    count++;
}
System.out.println("You need " + count + " times.");
```

Hi!

How does i++ effect on the result for if I code

```
for(int i=1; i<=88444300; )
```

it gives count 27 instead of 26?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a print statement in the loop to see the values of `i` / add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line / get a piece of paper and calculate `i` by hand.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(i);`  just before `i*= 2;` and see

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think to have got the point. i is added 1 after each loop and it makes it earlier to reach the value than the case without i++. Nice weekend to all!

Comment: You may want to have a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098) and/or [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid down-votes on your future questions.

Comment: Thanks Ivo for the hints! Will do it today. Nice Sunday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `i++` you are computing the series

i<sub>n+1</sub> = 2 *  i<sub>n</sub>

With it, you are computing

i<sub>n+1</sub> = 2 *  i<sub>n</sub> + 1

Unsurprisingly, the latter reaches the limit 88 444 300 more quickly (with fewer iterations).

Answer (score 0):

```
2^26 = 67 108 864
2^27 = 13 4217 728

2^26 < 88 444 300 < 2^27
```

You are starting with `i = 1` so answer should be 2^27

If I miss understood your question don't hesitate to ask in question :D

Comment: Thanks adian! You are rite, the answer should be 27. Still I doubt what makes i++ impose on the effect, for otherwise it shows 26.